# How can I install Icinga2 on Synology DSM?

Tags: installation, synology, icinga2

I want to monitor my home network with [Incinga2](https://www.icinga.com/). I'm using a Synology DS216se in my network. Does anyone know how I can get Incinga2 to run on the DSM 6.0?

Comment: Synology DSM has linux back end underneath the web GUI. You can ssh into it and supposedly build from source... I haven't done such a thing but it should be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that. I just wanted to know if there is a more easy way to do so... Some kind of "unofficial" package or something... I've found a tutorial to build [Nagios](https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/install-nagios-on-a-synology-diskstation-ds1813-or-ds412/) but I guess that's all a bit hacky... I will ask Synology if they maybe will make Icinga available as Package in their Repository.

Comment: I opened a package request as it still isn't available natively on Synology DSM [here](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/issues/2542)